# Make figure active without making it visible

Tags: matlab, graphics

I'm looping through a large number of figures while adding to axes in each of them.  Because there are many, I don't want them to be visible.  However, when I activate a figure, it becomes visible, as illustrated with the code below:

```
>> f1 = figure('visible', 'off');
>> f2 = figure('visible', 'off');
>> figure(f1);
```

Of course, I could have it followed immediately by `set(f1, 'visible', 'off');`, but is there some direct way of keeping `visible` set to `off` without resetting it "manually" after each `figure` call?

Comment: Have you actually tried to set the `'visible'` property `'off'` directly after activating the figure? I have one script doing that and it doesn't blink.

Comment: @user2482876 sorry, you're right, it doesn't.  It's still a bit annoying to have to do it manually though.  I've edited the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the axes when you create the figure, and use the axes handle to manipulate it later without activating explicitly the figure. Example

```
f1 = figure('visible', 'off');
a1=axes();
f2 = figure('visible', 'off');
a2=axes();
...
x=-1:0.01:1; y1=sin(2*pi*x); y2=cos(2*pi*x);
plot(a1, x, y1);
plot(a2, x, y2);
```

you can now make them visible to see the result;

```
set(f1, 'visible', 'on');
set(f2, 'visible', 'on');
```

Hope it helps.